# Valgrind error: invalid write of size 4 (but says error is in free() )

Tags: c, debugging, free, valgrind

First, here is the message valgrind gives me (this is just one error, I get the same message several times)

```
==25248== Invalid write of size 4
==25248==    at 0x4024B3A: free (vg_replace_malloc.c:366)
==25248==    by 0x8048F5E: sthread_free_ctx (sthread_ctx.c:86)
==25248==    by 0x80489C1: sthread_user_exit (sthread_user.c:105)
==25248==    by 0x804883C: dispatcher (sthread_user.c:40)
==25248==  Address 0x41a6148 is 65,376 bytes inside a block of size 65,536 free'd
==25248==    at 0x4024B3A: free (vg_replace_malloc.c:366)
==25248==    by 0x8048F5E: sthread_free_ctx (sthread_ctx.c:86)
==25248==    by 0x80489C1: sthread_user_exit (sthread_user.c:105)
==25248==    by 0x804883C: dispatcher (sthread_user.c:40)
```

I dont understand it, because I am used to getting this error when I dont malloc enough space, so why am I getting the error when I am trying to free something?? what is being written?

thanks

Comment: It's telling you what's wrong `Address 0x41a6148 is 65,376 bytes inside a block of size 65,536 free'd`. You're (most likely) freeing an invalid pointer.

Comment: Post the relevant lines of code.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is difficult to tell with so little information (particularly: no code), but it looks to me like you may be attempting to call `free` on a pointer which refers to an offset into a memory region which has already been freed by an earlier call to `free`. `free` needs to manipulate the heap data structures, so it is not surprising that it is attempting to write to the memory region.

Comment: ok, that makes sense! valgrind gives me no memory leaks when I remove the line (sthread_free_ctx()), so I will assume the context is free'd some other time then...Thanks!!